# Backtrack 5 R3 not detecting USB drive - macbook pro A1278 (EMC 2554*) dual boot

Tags: linux, mac, usb, drivers, usb-flash-drive

I have installed Backtrack 5 R3 and the USB drive I am trying to get some files from isn't being detected at all. Backtrack detects the ports, but not the device (USB thumb drive). The drive is formatted to FAT. It doesn't appear to be receiving power because the red light on the drive doesn't turn on. The furthest I have gotten (and I have tried a lot), is that I know that the usb-storage module doesn't load when I insert the drive. I have tried loading it manually, but that doesn't seem to change anything at all.

My computer specs: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.5-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html

Comment: i can only hear crickets lol

Comment: just realized for anyone who stumbles on this that Backtrack is no longer being maintained (it says so on their website) - provides a link for Kali which I am getting now - ADMINS - feel free to remove this question.